# What are the cons and pros of having the HR in my LinkedIn?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, career-development, ethics, human-resources

I started working with a mature and a big US based company a month ago. It seems promising. I am a fresh graduate, and I have been preparing myself to join this work force for the past years: Education, Profiles, References.. etc.

I just received a connect request via LinkedIn from the main HR person here.

I was wondering, are there any disadvantages when giving HR access to see my changes/updates? And what are some of the advantages of this so I can work on benefit from it?

Comment: It would depend on what kind of updates. There's the "I'm clearly looking for a new job" kind of updates, then there's the "Wow, that's amazing" kind of updates. Also note there's a setting to disable profile updates being sent to your connections.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I was wondering, are there any disadvantages when giving HR access to
>   see my changes/updates?

I would accept the request, as it will seem odd or as if your hiding something if you don't.

**Before** you do this, make sure you **turn off the setting that publishes notifications (updates) to your connections**.  This way if you wish to accept a connection request from a recruiter down the road, you HR person will not be notified.

> And what are some of the advantages of this so I can work on benefit
>   from it?

Opinions will vary here about the *usefulness of LinkedIn*.  **For me** its been a very valuable tool in regards to keeping current with former colleagues and gauging the value of my skill-set.  As you progress in your career, most likely future jobs will be obtained through networking, which is one of the main purposes of LinkedIn.